# What is a cross platform solution to keep my mobile app updated from a database?

Tags: mobile, xamarin, cross-platform, updates

Alrighty I have a cross platform mobile app built using xamarin and the mvvmcross framework. Part of the app is grabbing some data from a remote database. This data will be updated/deleted/created occasionally and i want to keep my users up-to-date. What's a good way to achieve this, preferably using cross platform code?

I can always set some kind of timer but I would much prefer a more elegant way.

Comment: You want to build something for your current database only? because with parse.com you can do what you want very efficient and professionally

Comment: Hey Tim, what is the current remote database that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Couchbase, as mentioned by Artur, is a great option - especially if doing disconnected editing. It does have a bit of a learning curve picking it up from scratch (which is totally worth it if you press on).

Consider Akavache (https://github.com/akavache/Akavache) as an alternative. It's well used and simpler but provides the basic capabilities you are asking about.

I recommend combining either approach with using ModernHttpClient (https://components.xamarin.com/view/modernhttpclient) which is basically just a drop-in component that gets you a performance boost.

Check out this excellent article by Rob Gibbens that covers using Akavache, ModernHttpClient, and other x-platform wholesome goodness: http://arteksoftware.com/resilient-network-services-with-xamarin/.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Couchbase Mobile
http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/couchbase-mobile
There is a wrapper for Xamarin
https://components.xamarin.com/view/couchbase-lite-net
With Couchbase you can save/update/synchronize data between your mobile device and cloud server using NoSQL DB.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of [Couchbase Mobile](http://bit.ly/MobileCB) for your use-case where you are **updating/deleting and creating your data occasionally**, you can replicate the data based on per method invocation.  This would happen once as oppose to replication that is on a continuous basis.

You would do this by defining the logic on when your PUSH and PULL replication would occur on a particular database endpoint.

---PUSH Replication would be from your mobile app/device to Couchbase Server(Cloud component) 
The library, Couchbase Lite (app component), on your app/device would flag new data or changes on existing documents(database) and will PUSH replicate to the Sync Gateway (data orchestration component).

---PULL Replication happens from the Couchbase Server(Cloud component) to mobile device. The Sync Gateway (data orchestration component) has advanced listeners that are observing for changes in the Couchbase Server and upon remote changes will pull data to the Sync Gateway and then update your mobile app/device.

I also suggest taking a look at the [mini-hack](http://bit.ly/mini-hack) quick tutorial, specifically the [Xamarin](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/mini-hacks/tree/master/kitchen-sync/xamarin/project) one on how to get a Xamarin app working with Couchbase Mobile.  And the mobile [Developer Portal](http://bit.ly/MobileCB) is a another great resource too where there are Xamarin Android & iOS guides.